# how to fix slow running program in debug mode

Tags: vb.net, winforms, debugging, data-binding

I have windows form program contains many binded controls  running under visual studio 2013 when I run it with debugging it is slow in loading data and more slow in add new data while without debug it run much faster

I tried to rebuild and clean solution  also deleted bin and obj folders and deleted visual studio user option (suo) and removed all breaking points and checked debug options

Comment: Debug mode will always run slower than non debug mode. That’s the name of the game ,  it has to load maps and symbol files and everything else vs studio needs to properly debug, so debug mode adds a lot of overhead to your process

Comment: It is very slow compared to without debug , I already tried many option in debug to solve this problem but it did not change

Comment: you’re missing the point  no matter what you try debug mode will ALWAYS run slower than non debug mode. No matter what

Answer (score 0):

I find that binding controls for checkbox 
is very slow when using checked 
ex.
            oType.DataBindings.Add(New Windows.Forms.Binding("Checked", BindingSource1, field, True))

while using

```
 oType.DataBindings.Add(New Windows.Forms.Binding("checkstate", BindingSource1, field, True))
```

it run instantly